# Make VS2019 use Yarn instead of NPM

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, yarnpkg

When I start running my ASP.Net Core/React webapp, it uses NPM to download the packages. I'd like it to use Yarn instead.

I can use Yarn from the command line and it restores the packages fine.
I've also installed [this](https://elanderson.net/2018/01/change-asp-net-core-from-npm-to-yarn/) extension which works great, using Yarn to restore packages, but only when I make a change to package.json.

What I need is a way to use Yarn when I checkout the code for the first time and hit the green 'Run' button in Visual studio, where it tries to run it, realises node_modules is missing, and then tries to download the packages.

I thought it might be a case of adding this kind of thing to my scripts section in package.json

```
"start": "yarn react-scripts start",
"build": "yarn react-scripts build",
```

But so far it always uses NPM.

Background: in the course of upgrading some packages to fix some other issues, NPM made a right mess, whereas Yarn does it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Why? What is the problem you're trying to solve? (if you have node, you have npm, and packages may make use of that fact in order to manage their own scripts even if you _personally_ like yarn for your own code)

Comment: If I use NPM to restore the packages (after a big upgrade that only Yarn seemed to cope with - a result of running 'npm audit fix --force), my solution works perfectly if I manually use Yarn to restore the packages (by running 'yarn' in the ClientApp folder). But when someone else comes to clone the solution, they're just going to go with the default behaviour and try to run it in VS, which will use NPM and fail. I know it will work if I can tell VS to use Yarn somehow.

Comment: The specific problem that I found only yarn could help me with seemed to be upgrading react-scripts to 4.0.3 (I think), which was a 'breaking change'.

Comment: react-scripts 100% works with npm, it is maintained by the React team at Facebook, and will _guaranteed_ work for default node installations, which means no yarn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the CSPROJ file.  I am not familiar with yarn to properly swap it out with npm, but this is how VS is able to build and publish dotnet + react/angular/vue projects.

If you do a file -> new ReactJs application you can dissect the CSPROJ fairly easily.

For example; Here VS is hooking into the `BeforeTargets="Build"`, so when the project is built, it can execute `npm install`.

```xml
<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    ...
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I made it work, was by using [Yarn.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Yarn.MSBuild). I installed it (on dotnet 6) with the command:

```
dotnet add package Yarn.MSBuild --version 1.22.19
```

And then use `YarnBuildCommand` - inside the `.csproj` file - to run `yarn` commands. For example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <YarnWorkingDir>$(SpaRoot)</YarnWorkingDir>
    <YarnBuildCommand>install --immutable --immutable-cache --check-cache</YarnBuildCommand>
    <YarnBuildCommand>run build</YarnBuildCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
```